When is the next Moderator Election?
I may run, but only if it isn't very soon, I want to get more of a feel for these cold, empty forums.

We don't run moderator elections until a site has graduated. That's not in the cards any time soon.
The good news: we don't have any plans to close up shop. 
If you are interested in helping out, some sites have had success building an audience with question challenges.

I have pioneered the challenge tag, but we need more active users to make it work!

There is now a moderator election occurring.  We must have graduated since this post.
